# Converting month column data to row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a dataset for time series analysis that looks like:

```
    Year    Jan Feb March   April   May  June   July    Aug Sep Oct Nev Dec
    2014    0   0   0       0       0    4      0       118 0   0   137 29
    2015    0   19  135     312     0    78     67      0   0   0   132 0
    2016    0   0   0       0       0    0      0       0   100 194 0   114
    2017    0   0   127     4       199  293    0       0   0   23  0   0
    2018    252 0   0       0       0    0      287     0   2   0   0   143
    2019    0   10  0       0       176  205    51      0   0   0   0   0
    2020    0   0   310     0       0    0      0       0   0   0   0   0
```

I want the data looks like below:

```
    Date        Value 

    2014-01     0
    2014-02     0
    2014-03     0
    2014-04     0
    2014-05     0
    2014-06     4
    .. .. ..   .. 
    2020-12     0
```

How could I convert the dataframe and shrink the columns into rows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us check `melt`

```
df.columns = df.columns[[0]].tolist() + list(range(1,13))
s = df.melt('Year')
s['Year-month'] = s[['Year','variable']].astype(str).agg('-'.join, 1)
s
Out[39]: 
    Year variable  value Year-month
0   2014        1      0     2014-1
1   2015        1      0     2015-1
2   2016        1      0     2016-1
3   2017        1      0     2017-1
4   2018        1    252     2018-1
..   ...      ...    ...        ...
79  2016       12    114    2016-12
80  2017       12      0    2017-12
81  2018       12    143    2018-12
82  2019       12      0    2019-12
83  2020       12      0    2020-12
[84 rows x 4 columns]
```